# Forgotten BIOS supervisor password--Lenovo B570

Tags: bios, passwords, cmos, lenovo-laptop

I've tried everything possible to reset the supervisor password on my Lenovo B570 laptop: looking for a non-existent CMOS battery, trying to run some of those software tools that are supposed to give you the answer, etc. Everything. Does anyone here know what I can do? I assure you that it is my laptop, and that the reason I am trying to do this is that Wi-Fi is disabled via BIOS and I can't turn it back on without the password my Dad forgot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Forgotten Supervisor password

A forgotten Supervisor password will prevent access to the ThinkPad BIOS setup utility. To regain access, the system will need to be serviced to have the system board and hard drive replaced. Proof of purchase is required, and this repair is not covered under the warranty.

I think you should take a look at these links : http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=migr-59377

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/67551-35-method-reset-bios-password-lenovo-motherboard

http://www.helpowl.com/q/Lenovo/B570/Reviews,-Ratings-and-Opinions/bypass-bios-password-lenovo-b570-laptop/196908

Unfortunately, there is no way to bypass the BIOS password of your Lenovo computer. This is set by the manufacturer to create security feature in your computer. However, the best thing you have to do is not to set any password in the BIOS if you don't need that security feature. You may only set your BIOS password if you believe that there are other people who might access you device without your permission.

Answer (score 1):

On iFixit, [@cinemastudio](https://www.ifixit.com/User/1499025/cinemastudio) wrote a guide for ThinkPad Mini 10 netbooks. I haven't tried it yet, but it looks very detailed.

- How to disable bios password on lenovo netbook: https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/128167/How+to+disable+bios+password+on+lenovo+netbook#answer289130

---

> ThinkPad Mini 10 netbooks
>
> you have to open up the back, and short the Eprom Bios reader use a
>   magnifying glass, find it, and it is pin 5 and 6 on the eprom, (SDA)
>   and (SDL) the eprom is the first selection of the motherboard that
>   when booted, it checks security on the system, be carefull powering on
>   the Notebook with the back cover off, turn the laptop on it's side,
>   boot the power on button, look for Circuit print (U46) that should be
>   the Eprom, (see pictures Below of the two different eproms you may
>   have) usually the eprom is adjacent halfway next to the hard drive,
>   some other thinkpads they are located under the ram, or next to the
>   BIOS battery.
>
> So With your Thinkpad rear cover removed, check to see if you can see
>   the bios battery and the chipsets, if so, it should be there on that
>   side of the circuit board....if not....then it's on the other side
>   which means you have to remove the entire back cover to get at it, i
>   would suggest you just remove the rear slide cover first or palm pad
>   screws, and check before removing your entire back cover for no
>   reason.
>
> What we need to do, is.... while booting up turning the power button
>   on at the same time holding a fine screwdriver to both pin 5 and 6
>   (the right hand two pins solders on the top end of the eprom.. doesnt
>   matter which way your looking at your circuit board, it will still be
>   the top last two in the right of the eprom, as they correspond and
>   switch over inside the eprom chip so you will be shorting either the
>   two "in'" or the 2 "outs"of the eprom chip....so doesn't make a
>   difference, you will still be shorting the circuit before or after it
>   goes to the next chip along the circuit board down th track, as long
>   as it's the top right two prong solders your touching on the eprom
>   chip (SEE PIC) ......do this short for only 2 seconds max.... this
>   should fail both the security Supervisor Password, and power on
>   Password and reset your Cmos.
>
> [image: eprom.jpg]
>   https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Image/meta/vcViHyoEXCYvRwmD
>
> What your initially trying to achieve by doing this is to make the
>   System forget to check Security settings during a few attempted boot
>   ups this way.....all you need is the System to forget once and your
>   in.
>
> an eprom is the tiny chip that has 4 inbound solders and 4 outbound
>   solders on the Eprom chip, ("again inside this eprom chip they switch
>   over so they aren't a direct pass through to the otherside of the
>   eprom chip"), so just make sure your touching the two top right end
>   solders of the eprom located on the circuit board, usually marked with
>   a fine print stamp on the eprom saying (Ps4508) or something like
>   (ATMEL G 282) orsimillar. Usually on the thinkpads it is located next
>   to the yellow Bios Battery cable under the tape, or under the ram, if
>   it is under the ram, take the ram out, you wont need the ram to get
>   into Bios anyway, once you think you have acheived it...check your
>   boot Bios menu whilst the pc is still on its side and select along
>   into the security settings and see if Supervisor and Power on
>   passwords are enterable to change.....if so you were succesful.
>
> Most of the Lenovo Thinkpads can be cracked this way....but be warned
>   you only need to create a short circuit for just a second.... and by
>   short circuit i mean strike those pins i mentioned for just a second
>   on reeboot, (only a low amp of 3 watts from the bios battery comes
>   through it) holding the screw driver any longer than 5 seconds will
>   fry your ALTMEL Chip on your motherboard.....you only need to
>   basically strike or swipe those pins for a second a during reeboot.
>
> [image: 1-140324152924.jpg]
>   https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Image/meta/Gl5NfaQ4TdwVFFnp
>
> you may need to do it roughly 3 times....i usually get it on the 3rd
>   boot attempt. just make sure your not stupid and panic and strike your
>   fine screwdriver through the rest of the motherboard.
>
> There is no backdoor or secret password or Boot CD software or
>   anything like that can break this or unlock it with the click of a
>   mouse or keyboard, most of the thinkpads are like that also, you will
>   have to replace the motherboard if your thinkpad is locked if you
>   don't wish to try this proceedure. Lenovo do however charge you to
>   unlock the Eprom, but a proof of purchase or reciept either new or
>   second hand is nessecary.
>
> i should also mention another type of lockout on these , another which
>   many students get is the HDD LOCKOUT.......this happens when too many
>   wrong passwords are entered, if you don't know the BIOS passwords DO
>   NOT TRY AND GUESS IT...You only have 3 attempts in one session.....if
>   you have entered too many times you will see the boot icon lock has a
>   number 1 or 2 on boot up, this it is not your BIOS, but your Hard
>   Drive that is locked, best option is taking out your HDD and putting
>   it into another laptop that fits the hard drive and get in and unlock
>   or remove the Hard Drive lock and then put it back into your thinkpad.
>
> also the ThinkPad Mini 10 netbook was mass produced by Lenovo for
>   Australian Schools in 2013
>
> they have since disregarded these and moved onto a simillar small
>   laptop with DELL.

Answer (score -2):

You don't really need to replace the system board. That is an overkill by a magnitude.

The information about BIOS is stored in a chip on your system board. Where it is stored differs from machine to machine. Typically it is stored in an [EEPROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM). If you erase and overwrite the chip the password will be gone. However it is not a straightforward task. First you have to identify where the chip is located on your system board. Then you have to reprogram it. To do it safely you need [FPGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array) programming tools.

There are also unsafe ways (which can burn your system board!) like connecting the clock and data pins of the EEPROM chip storing the BIOS password. You can try them at your own risk.

Comment: You do understand that FPGA programming tools cannot be used to program EEPROMs right?

Answer (score -3):

Try this for the Supervisor password: `sktlts`.